# Spring Boot Convention for Variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, javabeans

So I have an `application.yml` file for my spring boot application like so:

```
spring:
  url: localhost
email:
  from: something@gmail.com
app:
  uuid: 3848348j34jk2dne9
```

I want to wire these configuration properties into different components in my app like so:

```
@Component
public class FooA {
    private final String url;

    public FooA(@Value("${spring.url}") String url) {
        this.url = url
    }
}

@Component
public class FooB {
    private final String from;

    public FooA(@Value("${email.from}") String from) {
        this.from = from
    }
}

@Component
public class FooC {
    private final String uuid;

    public FooA(@Value("${app.uuid}") String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid
    }
}
```

The above works as intended in my application. But my question is if this is best practice in spring boot. The only other alternative to this that I know of is to use a `Properties` object by creating a bean inside of a configuration class, loading the properties with all the configuration variables and autowire the property bean into the components.

What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you have identified your two main choices for injecting configuration are using either `@Value` on individual properties or `@ConfigurationProperties` on a javabean configuration object.

Which one you use comes down to preference. Personally I prefer using a configuration object.

Using `@ConfigurationProperties` allows you to use JSR-303 bean validation.
You can also write your own custom validation in the setter of your javabean if you desire.
You can annotate config beans from non-spring projects, which allows you to write libraries that are easily configured but don’t depend on spring.
You can generate IDE meta-data from the objects that may make your development process smoother.

Here are some practices I recommend when using spring configuration.

- Create individual `@ConfigurationProperties` objects for logical components of your application. Try to keep things modular and avoid creating a dumping ground for your entire applications config.
- Don’t use the same `@Value` property in multiple locations.
  If the same configuration is needed in multiple places within your application then you should probably move the value into a config object.
  Using the same property across multiple `@Value` annotations makes it harder to reason around, and it can also cause unexpected behaviour if you define a default value by way of a "SpEL" expression in one place and not the other.
- Don't define your own properties in the `spring` namespace.
  For example your `spring.url` property [is not one of the properties defined in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).
  By using the same name space you run the risk of that name being used for something in future spring-boot versions.

Comment: I don't think Richard was considering the use of '@ConfigurationProperties'. The way I read his question, he was considering creating and populating a bean manually in his '@Configuration' class. So '@ConfigurationProperties' will be a great improvement. Also, if you add the spring-boot-configuration-processor, you can generate configuration metadata for IDEs, for autocompletion / validation / documentation, which is pretty cool!